# Windows batch file to delete .svn files and folders

Tags: batch-file, svn, delete-file

In order to delete all ".svn" files/folders/subfolders in "myfolder" I use this simple line in a batch file:

```
FOR /R myfolder %%X IN (.svn) DO (RD /S /Q "%%X")
```

This works, but if there are no ".svn" files/folders the batch file shows a warning saying: "The system cannot find the file specified."
This warning is very noisy so I was wondering how to **make it understand that if it doesn't find any ".svn" files/folders he must skip the RD command.**

**Usually using wild cards would suffice**, but in this case I don't know how to use them, because I don't want to delete files/folders with .svn extension, but I want to delete the files/folders named exactly ".svn", so if I do this:

```
FOR /R myfolder %%X IN (*.svn) DO (RD /S /Q "%%X")
```

it would NOT delete files/folders named exactly ".svn" anymore.
I tried also this:

```
FOR /R myfolder %%X IN (.sv*) DO (RD /S /Q "%%X")
```

but it doesn't work either, he deletes nothing.

Comment: are you aware of the SVN export function? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html "exports a clean directory tree from the working copy"

Comment: @nickf: thanks for telling me, but I had to accomplish a different task wher I need to delete the .svn files/folders.

Comment: Just a note, that with new versions of SubVersion (since 1.7), the .svn metadata folder is only at the root level of the checkout, not in every directory.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you can try

```
FOR /R myfolder %%X IN (.svn) DO (RD /S /Q "%%X" 2>nul)
```

Comment: This works only in batch files. When you use it directly in a console window, you sould drop the second %'s. So it sould be then:         FOR /R myfolder %X IN (.svn) DO (RD /S /Q "%X" 2>nul)

Answer (score 4):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d *svn') do (rd /s /q "%%i")
```

Comment: cmd prompt: for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /s /b /a:d *svn') do (rd /s /q "%i")

Answer (score 2):

Something like that using find :

```
rm -rf `find . -name ".svn" -type d`
```

Edit:

I know this is for linux (I read bash instead of batch). I'm leaving it here to help Linux users that would randomly end-up here :)

Comment: @nickf: what's wrong with "Windows batch file"? I mean a file with .BAT extension.

Comment: @Marco, there's nothing wrong with what you said. Niklaos just gave a unix based answer, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this answer is from Jesper Rønn-Jensen at 
`http://justaddwater.dk/2011/03/01/easy-delete-all-svn-subfolders-in-windows-explorer/`

I thought it was so much easier I'd share.  I'm converting several projects from .SVN to .GIT, so this was great.  It adds a menu item to Explorer so you can remove the folders.  Create a .reg file, and import it.

[image]

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
;
; Running this file will give you an extra context menu item in Windows Explorer
; "Delete SVN folders"
;
; For the selected folder, it will remove all subfolders named ".svn" and their content
; Tip from http://www.iamatechie.com/remove-all-svn-folders-in-windows-xp-vista/
;
; Enrichened with comments by Jesper Rønn-Jensen ( http://justaddwater.dk/ )
;
;
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN]
@="Delete SVN Folders"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN\command]
@="cmd.exe /c \"TITLE Removing SVN Folders in %1 && FOR /r \"%1\" %%f IN (.svn) DO RD /s /q \"%%f\" \""
```

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre sidenote: if I use

```
FOR /R . %%X IN (*.svn) DO (echo "%%X")
```

instead of

```
FOR /R myfolder %%X IN (.svn) DO (RD /S /Q "%%X")
```

not only does it list all directories ending in .svn, it lists ALL THEIR CONTENTS as well.  This is a BUG in the For command, it gave me an expansion where I gave it no wild card. Very strange.

Ken

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all sub folders named **.svn** in Windows
then create batch file with this content:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d *.svn') do (
rd /s /q "%%i"
)
```

save it in a file **del_All_Dot_SVN_Folders.cmd** . Run it. Your done.

Thanks to http://www.axelscript.com/2008/03/11/delete-all-svn-files-in-windows/

Remember the above code has .svn whereas the code in the link has only *svn so its better
to have the .svn to not accidentally have undesired effect.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my favorite, its simple and compact:

`find ./ -name ".svn" | xargs rm -Rf`

Fissh

Answer (score -2):

To delete all svn files on windows

```
for /d /r . %d in (.svn) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"
```

.svn is the folder name