# Delete all .svn and .project files using windows registry

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

A the moment I have a registry file which delete the .svn files when right clicking over directory. I would like to extend this windows registry file to also delete some temporary files created from Zend Studio:

- .buildpath
- .project
- .settings (directory)

Following the answers from this question: [Windows batch file to delete .svn files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532740/windows-batch-file-to-delete-svn-files-and-folders)

I have:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN]
@="Delete SVN Folders"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN\command]
@="cmd.exe /c \"TITLE Removing SVN Folders in %1 && COLOR 9A && FOR /r \"%1\" %%f IN (.svn) DO RD /s /q \"%%f\" \""
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you asking someone to implement the others for you?  Have you tried something and are having issues?

Comment: Yes I would like some help with delete the extra files also. I would try myself but I don't have any idea where to start

Comment: It sounds like you already have a starting point, namely the command line for deleting svn files. Just adapt it to delete the other files you want to delete.

Comment: Yes I already have a starting point but I don't really have a clue what the line of code is doing. The code is not very readable to a beginner. I have tried changing: (.svn) to (.svn,.settings) but this breaks the code

Comment: Note that for removal of .svn files there is also a standard svn command: `svn export` (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) which can be used through a shell extension such as turtoisesvn (http://tortoisesvn.net/features.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I have found this doesn't work when exporting from Zend Studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. I only made changes to the last line.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN]
@="Delete SVN Folders"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\DeleteSVN\command]
@="cmd.exe /c \"TITLE Removing SVN Folders in %1 && color 9A && for /r \"%~1\" %%F in (.) do (rd /s /q \"%%~fF\.svn\" \"%%~fF\.settings\" & del \"%%~fF\.buildpath\" \"%%~fF\.project\")2>nul \""
```

This solution is similar to what Laf was describing, except he suggested using && before the last command. I think that could give you problems because the next command would only execute if the RD was successful. But your current algorithm attempts to remove the directory from all subdirectories, even when it is not there. I used & so that the next command (DEL) always executes, regardless of the outcome of the RD. I extended the RD to delete both directories, and the added DEL command deletes both files.

I redirected stderr to nul so that you don't see a bunch of error messages. The algorithm is very inefficient and can generate a lot of error messages depending on the number of subdirectories.

If your requirements get any more complicated, or if you want to develop a more efficient script, you might be better off creating a batch file that does the work, and call the batch file from your registry entry. It's a bit messy to read and maintain a complicated set of commands on a single line. The escape sequences also become tiresome in the registry.

Answer (score 2):

Some details on the command currently implemented:

- `cmd.exe /c`: will call a new command interpreter, and execute the command that follows, then will quit (that's what `/C` does). The rest of the command (between the first and the last `\"` is the command that will be carried out by the command interpretter)
- `TITLE Removing SVN Folders in %1`: Changes the title of the command interpreter to "Removing SVN Folders in *folder*".
- `COLOR 9A`: changes the color scheme of your command interpreter
- `FOR /r \"%1\" %%f IN (.svn) DO RD /s /q \"%%f\"`: will delete all folders named *.svn* in the current folder.

%1 represent the folder on which you have right-clicked. The `&&` between the commands means that the command interpreter will execute all three commands one after another. What you should do is to add your own command at the end of the command-line, like:

`@="cmd.exe /c \"TITLE Removing SVN Folders in %1 && COLOR 9A && FOR /r \"%1\" %%f IN (.svn) DO RD /s /q \"%%f\" && *MyCommand*\""`

where *MyCommand* is the command you need to delete the temporary files.